# Snowflake execute immediate into variable

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in which one column contains SQL query that I want to execute. Those queries are some kind of quality check(for instance "select count(*) from the table where col = x"). So, now I iterate over rows from that table, take a specific query and I want to execute it, and take the actual value(result) from that query into a variable. Is this possible with Snowflake scripting?

Comment: That should be possible via a stored procedure.

Comment: Could you please elaborate in more detail? I'm using sp blocks, but don't know how to execute a query string into a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, If I understand what you want by "a variable"..

Little bit of setup:

```
CREATE table test.test2.to_do(checks string);

INSERT INTO to_do values ('select count(*) from test.test2.to_do;');
```

- Now some Snowflake Scripting to loop across a cursor from the "checks table"
- Then run that SQL
- Then capturing the results into a variable

```
declare
  counts int;
  total_counts int := 0; 
  c1 cursor for select checks from test.test2.to_do;
begin

  for record in c1 do
    execute immediate record.checks;
    
    select $1 into counts from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
    total_counts := total_counts + counts;
  end for;
  return total_counts;
end;
```

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| 1 |

Boost those Checks:

```
INSERT INTO to_do values ('select sum(10) from test.test2.to_do;');

select * from test.test2.to_do;
```

| CHECKS |
| --- |
| select count(*) from test.test2.to_do; |
| select sum(10) from test.test2.to_do; |

Run the script SQL above again:

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| 22 |

### But can we direct inject?

```
INSERT INTO to_do values ('select count(*) into counts from test.test2.to_do;');
INSERT INTO to_do values ('select sum(10) into counts from test.test2.to_do;');
```

alter the block:

```
declare
  counts int;
  total_counts int := 0; 
  c1 cursor for select checks from test.test2.to_do;
begin

  for record in c1 do
    execute immediate record.checks;
    
    --select $1 into counts from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
    total_counts := total_counts + counts;
  end for;
  return total_counts;
end;
```

and run:

> Error: 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 8 at position 4 : SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 0 INTO clause is not allowed in this context (line 8)

*NO* blocked, so last query it is..

Comment: You are like Snowflake magician :) Thank you. I do not like using  last_query_id(), but will be usefull in this case.

Comment: Hey @Simeon, Is there a way to pass the bind variable to the cursor when using for loop, as you did it here?